# How do I enable the Newsletter Plugin for CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, configuration, newsletter

I want to put a newsletter in my website and I am using the following plugin:

https://github.com/edap/cakephp-newsletter-plugin

I already followed these steps:

Step 1: http://iandeth.dyndns.org/mt/ian/archives/20120110-cakephp-extendassociations-behavior/ExtendAssociations2Behavior.txt
save it under `Models/Behavior/ExtendAssociationsBehavior.php`

Step 2: You MUST have a sendEmail() function in your Appcontroller, like follow

```
public function sendEmail($subject, $message, $address) {
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $email->from(array('your@email.com' => 'My Site'));
    $email->to($address);
    $email->subject($subject);
    $email->send($message);
}
```

Step 3: drop the plugin files in the folder `app/Plugins/Newsletter/`

Step 4: create the necessary DB tables using the file in `app/plugins/newsletter/config/sql/schema.sql`

Step 5: Add this variable to your `app/Config/bootstrap.php` file

I am stuck at the next step:

Step 6: JQuery for ajax calls in `admin_send.ctp`

Step 7: Explain Configuration Fields

```
$subject = Configure::read('Newsletter.unsubscribe_subject');
$subject = Configure::read('Newsletter.subscribe_subject');
$from = Configure::read('Newsletter.from'); #Required
$from_email = Configure::read('Newsletter.from_email'); #Required

$subject = Configure::read('Newsletter.sendX'); #Number of emails to sent at each admin_send call.
$subject = Configure::read('Newsletter.sendInterval'); #the interval time before send next batch
$subject = Configure::read('Newsletter.mail_opt_out_message');
$subject = Configure::read('Newsletter.emptyImagePath');
```

Can anyone help me? How can I add the form so the user can input their email?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, why Configure::read is used in  the bootstrap here, just 
add the following global variables to your app/Config/bootstrap.php:

```
Configure::write('Newsletter.unsubscribe_subject','Text for unsubscribe...');
Configure::write('Newsletter.subscribe_subject','Text for you subscribe subject... ');
Configure::write('Newsletter.from','Your Name here..'); #Required
Configure::write('Newsletter.from_email','Your e-mail here...'); #Required
Configure::write('Newsletter.confirm_url','http://www.example.com/YourAppname/newsletter/subscriptions/confirm_subscription/'); #Required


Configure::write('Newsletter.sendX',100); #Number of emails to sent at each admin_send call.
Configure::write('Newsletter.sendInterval',100); #the interval time before send next batch
Configure::write('Newsletter.mail_opt_out_message','Opt out message here...');
Configure::write('Newsletter.emptyImagePath','no clue what that is...');
```

If you want to see the subscription Form, your url should look like this:

http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourapp/newsletter/subscriptions/subscribe

I hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin for newsletter in CakePHP.
[Cake2 newsletter](https://github.com/lemonkazi/cake2-newsletter-plugin)